# How to do mouse selection on grid? Monogame/XNA

Tags: c#, grid, xna, mouse, monogame

I am creating a game that uses tile based combat on a portion of the screen. I have already mapped a 2d array of nodes (each with a corner position to draw my units) and I have already done some tests with drawing the actual units. Now I need to start working on mouse selection, but am having trouble finding a way to map a mouse click to a particular node in the array. I have the positions stored in each node, but I don't know how exactly to use them. I would like to be able to have someone left click a square and have a way to register which square I actually selected. Any help?

[This is an example of part of my grid which is in the bottom half of my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xaisx.png)

Comment: Show where your cell positions are stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rectangle` has a method `Contains(Point)`, and you can use it to easily detect if a point is inside the rectangle.

---

Assume your `Node` class has a property `BoundingRectangle`.

```
class Node
{
    // ...
    public Rectangle BoundingRectangle
    {
        get { return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height); }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now to handle mouse clicks:

```
MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    foreach (Node n : nodes)
    {
        if (n.BoundingRectangle.Contains(mouseState.Position))
        {
            // TODO: Code to handle node being clicked...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, I'll look into this.